# ImportError when Importing Python Module into Java Program in Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jython

I have written a simple function in python that I want executed by Jython's PythonInterpreter. The problem is, I'm not sure where the .py class needs to go.

I have tried in the same package as the Java class, the same working directory as well as another folder.

[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

I am interested in the above method, but I do not want to use an absolute path as I intend to make this program available for other people to use.

Here is my workspace layout:

[image: layout]

I will be invoking the function in myscraper.py from EntryManagement.java. The function is defined as follows:

```
def validateUrl(url):
  try: 
    uReq(url)
    return(1)
  except URLError:
    return(0)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used OS to get the current working directory and worked from there, using sys.path

```
interpreter.exec("sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + '\\src\\python')");
interpreter.exec("from myscraper import validateUrl");
```